# '{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(*octets) 'C0A80001'

Tags: python, format

I read the [string — Common string operations — Python 3.7.2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

The below example is easy to follow:

```
>>> "int: {0:d};  hex: {0:x};  oct: {0:o};  bin: {0:b}".format(42)
'int: 42;  hex: 2a;  oct: 52;  bin: 101010'
```

As to the instance

```
>>> octets = [192, 168, 0, 1]
>>> '{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(*octets)
'C0A80001
```

What does :02 do here? Seem hare to get its idea.
'

Comment: It's converting the integers in `octets` to hexadecimal format, and padding those hex digits up to 2 places.